# Summary of how mathematicians have been able to reduce the number of maps to check in the Four Color theorem

Tags: graph-theory

I'm doing an essay on the effectiveness of the ability of computers to help prove the Four Color Theorem. I've looked a lot online but I have not found a good resource specifically answering how mathematicians have been able to reduce the number of maps to check. I also don't have any good resources on the actual algorithm Haken-appel has used. If someone can help provide me some resources or just summarize the answers that would be really helpful.

Comment: If you do not get an answer here, perhaps try also https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: @Tortoise Sigh, no luck there, nobody would provide help.

Comment: Yes, I have read the comments there. Strange. Sometimes I understand what is said. Sometimes not. Anyways. I am no expert on the 4-colour-theorem. Perhaps check out "http://www.ams.org/journals/era/1996-02-01/S1079-6762-96-00003-0/S1079-6762-96-00003-0.pdf". If this does not help you, then - perhaps - you have to conclude that the specific of "how" the reductio nof maps was actually done is not so easy to find out. Good luck.

Comment: @Tortoise Thanks man, at least you tried. I guess I'll just read along and if I get stuck I'll ask here again. Thanks for the luck, hope good fortune comes in your mathematical career :)

Comment: You are very kind! I wish the same to you.